# How do you properly test for loop queries within test classes?

Tags: unit-testing, class, for-loop, salesforce

I have a Schedulable class which will get called once per night.  I have run the code anonymously and everything works as it should.  The problem I am having is that I cannot get proper test coverage on it!  I have written a test class that I believe should work, but for some reason any lines within my for-loops are not being covered.

I assume that it is because no data is being returned from these queries, however there are thousands of records that should be returned.  I have run the queries on the production environment without any issues.

Is there a separate process for running queries in a schedulable class?

**Here's part of my class:**

```
global class UpdateUnitPrice  implements Schedulable{

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){

        // OwnerId -> List of Strings with Row Contents
        Map<Id,Map<Id,Map<String,String>>> updateContainer = new Map<Id,Map<Id,Map<String,String>>>{};  // Covered

        List<Id> ownerContainer = new List<Id>{};  // Covered

        String EmailMessage;     // Covered
        String EmailLine;        // Covered
        String EmailAddedLines;  // Covered

        String CurrentEmailLine; // Covered
        String NewEmailLine;     // Covered

        List<Id> opportunityList = new List<Id>{};  // Covered

        for(Opportunity thisOpp :[SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Order_Proposed__c = null])
        {
            // Thousands of records should be returned

            opportunityList.add(thisOpp.Id); // NOT COVERED!!

        }

        List<OpportunityLineItem> OppLineItemList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>{};  // Covered

        for(OpportunityLineItem thisOppProd : [SELECT Id,OpportunityId,Opportunity.OwnerId,Opportunity.Name,Product_Name__c,UnitPrice,ListPrice 
                                               FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                                               WHERE OpportunityId IN :opportunityList
                                               AND UnitPrice_lt_ListPrice__c = 'True'
                                               ORDER BY OpportunityId ASC])
        {

            . . . // NO LINES COVERED WITHIN THIS LOOP

        }


      . . .

    }

}
```

**Here's my test class:**

```
@isTest
private class UpdateUnitPriceTest {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        Test.startTest();

        // Schedule the test job 
        String jobId = System.schedule('UpdateUnitPrice','0 0 0 3 9 ? 2022',new UpdateUnitPrice());

        // Get the information from the CronTrigger API object
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId];

        // Verify the expressions are the same
        System.assertEquals(ct.CronExpression,'0 0 0 3 9 ? 2022');

        // Verify the job has not run
        System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);

        // Verify the next time the job will run
        System.assertEquals('2022-09-03 00:00:00', String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));

        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Am I supposed to specifically reference something within these for-loops for them to fire?  This Class should be able to just run everything on it's own without inserting records for testing.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Comment: Log the result of the query during the test, to see if you really are getting any records during the test.

Comment: Running that now.  Is there any reason why the queries would return nothing on the test class?

Comment: I'm not a SalesForce expert, but my guess would be insufficient permissions to the database during testing (not being properly authenticated).

Comment: I don't think that is it, the tests are run as my user, which is an admin account.  Results should be returned... (in theory)

Comment: Maybe try to create an SystemAdmin Test-User (within the test class) and testing with that admin. More info [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) And i would output at least `thisOpp` like `System.debug('#### thisOpp: ' + thisOpp.size());`If there is no records returned by the query - the problem is there.

Comment: @mast0r - It had to do with a new test class implementation of API 24.0.  See my answer below.  So much frustration for such a little piece of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a lovely feature added to API 24.0 which requires test classes to include a small (new) line of code in order to view queried data.  I have no idea why this was implemented, but it sure did trip me up.

***For our test classes to run properly, they now must have the following at the top:***

```
@isTest (SeeAllData = true)
```

***Previously, all that was needed was:***

```
@isTest
```

**You can read more on test classes and this new "feature" here: [Apex Test Class Annotations](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm)**

Comment: I know I'm not the only one to get tripped up by this... haha